# MIPS - Program Halting After JAL command

Tags: mips, mips32

Homework:  I am trying to write in MIPS for the first time, and I am stuck on the JAL command. When I run a sub routine called `setup_ports` everything works as advertised (i.e. it goes into the subroutine, executes the code, and exits).  The next function (`wait_for_operation`) calls another function `light_leds`.  Problem is the code halts at this line.  The debugger does not step into the `light_leds`, it simply halts.  I'm not sure what the problem is.

Correctly working code:

```
.ent setup_ports
setup_ports:
#set leds to input, RB10-11
LI $t0, 0x3C00
SW $t0, TRISBCLR

#set switches to output, RE08, RD00, RD08, RD13
LI $t0, 0x100
SW $t0, TRISESET
LI $t0, 0x2101
SW $t0, TRISDSET
JR $ra
.end setup_ports
```

Code not working:

```
 .ent wait_for_operation
 wait_for_operation:
 MOVE $s1, $ra
 LI $t0, 0xF
 MOVE $a0, $t0
 JAL light_leds
 NOP
 SW $t0, ($zero)

.ent light_leds
light_leds:
#clear all lights
LI $t0, 0x3C00
SW $t0, LATBCLR
#get passed value
MOVE $t0, $a0
```

The Debugger halts at `JAL light_leds` line and doesn't allow pausing, only stopping.

Comment: Are you sure the `jal` is the problem? On the previous line you are storing to the address `0xF`. Why `0xF`? Usually this would cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Fixed, but that was not the problem.